# When custom attribute applied to range of attributed String, typing attributes does not posses custom attributes in that range, why so?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm applying custom attribute for selected text, which works fine, but when I modify text in applied attributed text, the newly entered text does not have custom attribute. If this is a standard behaviour then what should I do to achieve the behaviour I want.

What I'm doing :

1. Enter text in UiTextView e.g. : "This is a sample text"
2. Select all text
3. Apply Custom attribute
4. Log attributed Text

Log output

> This is a sample text{
>       MyCustomAttributeKey = CustomAttributeValue;
>       NSFont = " font-family: \".SFUIText\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt";
>       NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0,
>   FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0,
>   LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n
>   140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n
>   308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n),
>   BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation
>   NO, HeaderLevel 0"; }

5. Now insert text in between the text ,here, e.g. "modified" , complete text after modification : "This a modified sample text"
6. Log attributed Text

Now I'm getting log output (log is formatted to have clarity)

> This is a { MyCustomAttributeKey = CustomAttributeValue; NSFont = "
>   font-family: \".SFUIText\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;
>   font-size: 14.00pt"; NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0,
>   ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent
>   0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0,
>   LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n 28L,\n 56L,\n 84L,\n 112L,\n 140L,\n 168L,\n
>   196L,\n 224L,\n 252L,\n 280L,\n 308L,\n 336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0,
>   Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0,
>   TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0"; }
>
> modified { NSFont = " font-family: \".SFUIText\"; font-weight: normal;
>   font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt"; NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment
>   4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0,
>   HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0,
>   LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n 28L,\n 56L,\n 84L,\n
>   112L,\n 140L,\n 168L,\n 196L,\n 224L,\n 252L,\n 280L,\n 308L,\n
>   336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n),
>   BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation
>   NO, HeaderLevel 0"; }
>
> sample text{ MyCustomAttributeKey = CustomAttributeValue; NSFont = "
>   font-family: \".SFUIText\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;
>   font-size: 14.00pt"; NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0,
>   ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent
>   0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0,
>   LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n 28L,\n 56L,\n 84L,\n 112L,\n 140L,\n 168L,\n
>   196L,\n 224L,\n 252L,\n 280L,\n 308L,\n 336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0,
>   Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0,
>   TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0"; }

My expected output was to have custom attribute applied to newly entered text, but it's not. How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

My ViewController and Code :

```
//  ViewController.swift


import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    let customAttributeStringKey: NSAttributedStringKey = NSAttributedStringKey.init(rawValue: "MyCustomAttributeKey")

    @IBOutlet weak var textV: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    @IBAction func applyCustomAttribute(_ sender: Any) {
        let attributedString : NSMutableAttributedString = textV.attributedText.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
        attributedString.addAttribute(customAttributeStringKey, value: "CustomAttributeValue", range:textV.selectedRange)
        textV.attributedText = attributedString
    }

    @IBAction func logAttribute(_ sender: Any) {
        print(textV.attributedText.description)
    }

}
```

[image: ViewController UI]

P.S. : Experimented using NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle (instead of custom attribute),

```
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range:textV.selectedRange)
```

in this case modified text also gets underlineStyle attribute, then what's the problem with customAttribute?

Edit : progress

I tried setting typing attributes in textview listener method as below this partially work... but there is a but

```
  func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
         if(isApplyAttributesClicked){  //this flag is true when we have applied attributes by clicking Apply attribute button
            textV.typingAttributes = [customAttributeStringKey.rawValue:"CustomAttributeValue"]
        }
        return true
    }
```

But now problem is that whenever prediction or auto correct is selected from keypad then next typed word's typing attribute is not having a custom attribute.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are applying the attributes (like start and end of the text range or something similar.) to a specified text only.

Comment: Maybe by looking at `typingAttributes` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618629-typingattributes) what's its value when you insert content?

Comment: @Larme Yes, you are right, textview.typingAttribute does not contain custom attribute value, but how to fix this? I tried setting custom attribute value manually to textview.typingAttribute it did not solve problem.

Comment: Maybe listening to the selection change, get the current attributes and set it to the typingatrributes (since it’s cleared) ?

Comment: @Larme great suggestion I tried it.  I tried manually setting custom attribute [key:value] to textview.typingAttribute in textViewDidChangeSelection listener function. It did not solve problem, same log as in asked question. Not able to figure out when its vanishing.